# Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

i know why of this error, but i don't know how to fix it. here is the situation:
I have a tableA which have the next columns `userID`, `switch`, `plateType`, `groupVal`, `brokeage`.
`userID`, `plateType` and `groupVal` represent a unique key. `groupVal` and `userId` may take many different values but `plateType` just can have 4(A,B,C,D).
An example of the records for one `userId` and one `groupVal` will be:

```
Userid-------plateType------ groupVal------- brokeage
UserA---------  A----- ------------        3---------------        5.5
UserA---------  B----- ------------        3---------------        7.6
UserA---------  C----- ------------        3---------------        2.1
UserA---------  D----- ------------        3---------------        3.5
```

So when i run the next query if this records don't exist then will be created but if they exist they are supposed to be updated, but this error is what i get:

> Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row

```
Insert into tableA (userID, plateType, groupVal, brokeage) 
Select 'UserB', plateType, groupVal, brokeage from tableA  
 where userID = 'UserA' 
on duplicate key 
 Update brokeage = (Select brokeage from tableA  where userID = 'UserA')
```

I know it is in the subquery, the select that i use in the update...so what i really need is to select from `tableA` the records where `userId = UserA` but that matches with the `groupVal` and `plateTypes` that must be updated of `UserB`. i hope i make myself clear and someone can give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the values in your `SELECT` statement, which means you don't need a subquery at all. When we reference the table used in the SELECT, you can use the value in the UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (userID, plateType, groupVal, brokeage) 
SELECT 'UserB', plateType, groupVal, brokeage 
  FROM tableA AS t 
  WHERE userID = 'UserA' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
-- Set value of `brokeage` for UserB to the one set for UserA, from the SELECT
UPDATE brokeage = t.brokeage
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is that it updates, but all with the same value. Example if userA has 3.5 brokeage in plateType D, all the lines of UserB in brpokeage will take this value.

Comment: re-reading your question, you don't even need the subquery at all, see my edit.